# Why is this combined usage of cookies and sessions working? Confused

Tags: php, session, cookies

**I'm confused as to why this is working;**

```
setcookie("user", $user_id, time()+604800);
session_start();
$_SESSION['user_id'] = "string";
```

Even though `setcookie()` contains no reference to `$_SESSION['user_id']`, when I echo `$_SESSION['user_id']` from another page with the code:

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['user_id'];
```

It prints `string`.

I was under the impression that `setcookie()` had to reference a `$_SESSION` key in order for it to be called from any page?

Perhaps I'm well off base, but I just want to make sure I understand why this is working before I implement it, as I'd rather it not fault because of incorrect usage.

Any help, comments, advice and explanations will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[setcookie()](http://php.net/setcookie) sends a generic cookie to the browser while [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) initializes a session **and** sends a session cookie to the browser. With `setcookie()`, you can send whatever you want in the cookie, such as the user's username and password to be remembered between visits, or any arbitrary text. Note that all of this is stored right in the cookie itself and can be manipulated by the user and therefore should not be trusted.

With `session_start()`, on the other hand, everything is handled server-side. The only thing sent in the cookie is the session identifier. Session data cannot be directly manipulated by the browser. PHP also handles collision prevention, data storage (which by default is a plain text file viewable only by root and stored in /tmp) and expiration (even if the cookie is manipulated by the browser.)

Essentially, even though these functions are similar in that they both send a cookie to the browser, they both serve completely different purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Only the *session id* is stored in a cookie; that's used to link multiple requests from the same user as one session. Upon sending a request from the client, the session id from the cookie is sent in the request, and the server uses that id to identify the client and retrieve the contents of the session. The actual variables stored in the session are stored on the server.

Comment: I take it you mean it's stored by default or something? As I haven't actually requested that `$_SESSION['id]` be stored manually.

Comment: PHP handles this automatically when you start a session. HTTP is a stateless protocol by design, and the only thing that makes a session works as a session is the cookie containing the session id. The _contents_ of the session are controlled by you, and stored server-side.

Comment: So is that a different cookie than one created by `setcookie()` as in my OP. I also found this which I think might be what you're talking about - http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

Answer (score 0):

Cookies and sessions are two entirely different systems.

PHP's sessions does use a unique session ID in a cookie to track sessions, but any other cookies set will not affect it, and sessions are not stored in cookies (they're stored server side in memory or files depending on your php config).

session_start() creates that unique session ID and stores it in the cookie.

$_SESSION['user_id'] = 'string' sets the variable on the server side.

On next page refresh it grabs the session from the unique session ID and populates the $_SESSION variable with everything set in the other requests.

Comment: So how comes this is working then? I thought `SID` had to be declared as a url parameter for a session to be passed - http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php (It also mentions something about a session cookie?)

Comment: It usually defaults to cookies first, look in your cookies for PHPSESSID, that is typically the session PHP generated for you.