# Saving users database credentials in sessions (user interface for a theme)?

Tags: php, session

I'm building a UI to configure the settings of a theme (non WP, custom framework) I'm working on. Part of the requirements of that theme is database access.

I would, ideally, like to give the user the option to save his/her database credentials (host, user, pass, name) to be picked up next time the UI is loaded. Is is it safe to save that data in a session on that user's computer?

Or should I look into using `fwrite()` to create a seperate file, and write that data to it?

The first idea just seems quicker, but I just want to make sure that it's actually safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "session on the user's computer". What you're referring to are [Cookies](http://php.net/cookies). There's functions built into PHP for handling those, like `setcookie()`. Storing credentials in the cookie is never *really* safe - however, it is a method that's frequently used. When a website offers to 'remember you', they're actually storing a cookie with your username + password, so you can be logged automatically on the next visit.

Comment: See, I didn't even think about that (the fact that other websites are using the exact same principle). So what's the/is there a difference between a cookie and a session cookie, as you needn't use `setcookie()` with `start_session()` in order to get data stored in say `$_SESSION['user']`?

Comment: From what I've seen `start_session()` sets a cookie of it's own, which is what I think I was referring to, using `start_session()` and `$_SESSION['db_name'] = $db_name;` etc.

Comment: Exactly - for more information, read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260157/why-is-this-combined-usage-of-cookies-and-sessions-working-confused/7260212